# How to make msvc 2019 not to use XMM registers?

Tags: java, c++, optimization, visual-studio-2019, cpu-registers

I have a problem related to a bug in jdk 1.8. [JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8067744).
It says that calling JNI_CreateVM can corrupt the values of the XMM7, XMM8 and XMM15 registers.
the problem is that due to optimizations the vs2019 compiler decides to use the XMM8 register, but after that the code initializes the JVM and the value inside the XMM8 register becomes corrupted. so I need to somehow tell vs2019 not to use XMM registers for optimization purposes. How to do it?

Comment: Assuming (from your tags) that you're talking about C++ code, then you'd have to disable **all** use of "Enhanced Instruction Sets" in the project's settings. (The 'lowest' enhancement that VS-2019 supports is SSE instructions.)

Comment: Can't you write an asm wrapper for `JNI_CreateVM` that saves and restores those 3 XMM registers?

Comment: Have you tried the workaround in the issue description or simply updating to a build with the fix?

Comment: @AdrianMole is it possible for X64 build?

Comment: There no way to force the MSVC x64 compiler to avoid XMM registers. In the x86 compiler, you could use ``/arch:IA32`` which turns off *all* use of SSE/SSE2 by the compiler, but SSE/SSE2 is part of the x64 native architecture. The only option is to write an x64 assembly function that wraps the call to ``JNI_CreateVM`` so you can explicitly save off and restore the impacted registers. Otherwise, you could use clang/LLVM for Windows to build the specific module as they do expose "inline assembly" for x64.